# Why are const record parameters passed by value?

Tags: delphi, parameters, record

If I have a record e.g.

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    x : string;
  end;
```

And a `procedure test(const x : TMyRec);`.  Why is that parameter passed by value (i.e. a copy is passed in) and not by reference.  I would have thought from an efficiency point of view it should be passed by reference (like say an integer).

Comment: Because of the record's size. This is explained in [program control](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Program_Control_(Delphi)#By_Value_vs._By_Reference).

Comment: This is basically the whole purpose of records. You can optionally pass it as a pointer, if you wish.

Comment: Why would it be more efficient that way?

Comment: Passing by reference would probably be more efficient for large records (no need to copy), but for small records like this, passing by reference would most definitelly be less efficient (indirect access instead of direct access).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had though that all records would be treated the same, but it is dependent on their size.

Comment: @rudy We aren't talking about large records

Comment: @David: indeed. That is why pass by value for this record is **not** more efficient . On the contrary to what Alister thought, it is less efficient.

Comment: @rrudy Which is what I was getting at. So I am confused by your comment.

Comment: @David: my initial comment said the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is related to the size of the record, for

```
procedure test(const x : TMyRec);
```

the type

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    x : Array[1..4] of byte;
  end;
```

would be passed by value, and

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    x : Array[1..5] of byte
  end;
```

would be passed by reference on 32 bit, for 64 bit we would need a record of 9 bytes to be passed by reference on Tokyo (10.2.3) or earlier, Rio (10.3) behaves the same on both 32 and 64 bit.  Thanks to everyone who comment on my question, and provided additional references/suggestions.

See the Tokyo Documentation [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Program_Control_(Delphi)#By_Value_vs._By_Reference).  In particular

> Value and constant (const) parameters are passed by value or by reference, depending on the type and size of the parameter:

...

> Sets, records, and static arrays of 1, 2, or 4 bytes are passed as
>   8-bit, 16-bit, and 32bit values. Larger sets, records, and static
>   arrays are passed as 32-bit pointers to the value. An exception to
>   this rule is that records are always passed directly on the stack
>   under the cdecl, stdcall, and safecall conventions; the size of a
>   record passed this way is rounded upward to the nearest double-word
>   boundary.

If you want to force a pass-by-reference, you can declare your parameter as `const [ref]`, like so:

```
procedure test(const [ref] x : TMyRec);
```

Comment: Why not refer to the documentation?

Comment: @As of Delphi Rio, the 5 bytes record would be passed by reference in 64 bit too. Not so in older versions. This is one of the changes that came with Rio. It was done so the headers generated for 32 bit and 64 bit code would not have to differ.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan and Rudy, I've updated my answer with these observations.

Comment: @Rudy Is that change documentated? I didn't see a reference when I read the Rio What's New topic.

Comment: @David: it is documented, but only in the [What's New](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/What%27s_New#C.2B.2B.2FDelphi_ABI_compatibility) and not very clearly: "In previous releases, there were subtle platform differences in the ABI underlying method passing, especially for records between 4 and 8 bytes in size when passed by value or by reference."